# Return the word with the highest score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to define a function that returns the word with the highest score. Firstly, I made a dictionary (because there are letters who have no punctuation and others have the same). So, imagine I have best(["Babel", "Xadrez"]). It is supposed to return "Xadrez", because it has 21 points against the 10 points of the other word, but I'm not getting it.
This is my code by now:

```
def best(lista):

  dic = {'D':2, 'C':2, 'L':2, 'P':2, 'B':3, 'N':3, 'F':4, 'G':4,
   'H':4, 'V':4, 'J':5, 'Q':6, 'X':8, 'Y':8, 'Z':8}

 for i in range(len(lista)):
     if lista[i] >= 'A' and lista[i] <= 'Z':
        lista.append(lista[i])
 return lista

 txt = lista

 soma1 = 0
 soma2 = 0
 soma3 = 0
 for palavra in txt:
     soma1 = soma1 + dic.get(palavra, 0)

 for palavra in txt:
     soma2 = soma2 + dic.get(palavra, 0)

 for palavra in txt:
     soma3 = soma3 + dic.get(palavra, 0)

#I think the problem starts here, because we don't know where the next
 #word starts neither how many words there are
 if soma1 > soma2 and soma1 > soma3:
   return soma1
 elif soma2 > soma1 and soma2 > soma3:
   return soma2
 else:
   return soma3
#I know that this returns the punctuation of the word instead of the 
 #word itself, but I did it for just a reason: if the code was right
 #it would be easy to return the word
 #Thanks.
```

Comment: The simplest way to write this is to write a simpler function that returns the score  of a word, and then use it as a key function, so all you need is `def best(lista): return max(lista, key=score_of_word)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.   
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your incorrect indentation prevents this from passing the parser.  Since you never call this function, the posted code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Shouldn't `xadrez` only score 18 points?

Comment: I forgot @chrisz others worth 1 point

Comment: So then shouldn't you be using `dic.get(letter, 1)`?

Comment: What is that first loop supposed to do? It looks like it's trying to just add a second copy of every capital letter in the list onto the end of the list, but… why? And then you just `return lista` after the loop, so the rest of the code doesn't run, so it doesn't even get near the part where you say the problem appears.

Comment: Also, why do you build three different variables `soma1`, `soma2`, and `soma3` that all have the exact same value? I feel like there's some intended logic there I must be missing, but I can't work out what it's supposed to be.

Comment: I think I didn't get it @abarnet , does that function really sums up every letter of the word and recognizes where the next word starts? If is that, that's great. Thanks.

Comment: @abarnet that was because I was trying to do with two or three words to sse the result, if it was good I would generalize it

Comment: You don't have to recognize when the next word starts—you have a list of words, so you just loop over the words in that list (or let `max` do the looping for you internally). When you do `for word in lista:`, word is `'Babel'` the first time, and `'Xadrez'` the second time. And when you do `for i in range(len(lista)):`, likewise, `lista[0]` is `'Babel'` and `lista[1]` is `'Xadrez'`.

Comment: Yo're right @abarnert didn't even noticed that. My idea was to 3 txt and each of them corresponded to a word.. But it woul be difficult then to generalize, because I would need to write n txts

Comment: Thanks @abarnert ! It was my biggest doubt, if lista[0] was the first letter or the first word!

Comment: OK, if `lista` is a list of two words, then `lista[0]` is the first word, and `lista[0][0]` is the first character of the first word.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot! @abarnert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this `best` function by factoring out the code to score a word. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, so this might be oversimplified for your actual problem, but it should be enough to get you going:

```
def score(word):
    dic = {'D':2, 'C':2, 'L':2, 'P':2, 'B':3, 'N':3, 'F':4, 'G':4, 'H':4, 'V':4, 'J':5, 'Q':6, 'X':8, 'Y':8, 'Z':8}
    total = 0
    for char in word:
        total += dic.get(char.upper(), 0)
    return total
```

Now, if you have a list of words, you can use that `score` function as a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) and just pass it to [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
def best(lista):
    return max(lista, key=score)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @abarnet !!! I was trying now by that way, but wasn't getting it! I think I got now the basic of the dictionaries in Python! Thanks!